# Create Azure Service Bus policy with multiple claims in Azure Management libraries for .NET

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, .net-standard, azure-management-api

I'm using the [Azure Management libraries for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net) with Azure Service Bus. My objective is to create an Shared access policy with *Send* and *Listen* claims. I can do this in the Azure Portal.

[image: Policy created in the azure portal]

```
IServiceBusNamespace serviceBus = ...
IBlank policyDefinition = serviceBus.AuthorizationRules.Define("MySendAndListenPolicy2");
```

From `IBlank` I can call `WithListeningEnabled()` or `WithSendingEnabled()`. Both return an `IWithCreate`, which I can only create the rule from (i.e. `Create()` and `CreateAsync()`. There doesn't seem to be an option to configure both *Send* and *Listen*.

How can I create a policy with *Send* and *Listen* using the Azure Management .NET SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've achieved this by using the **Inner** objects of the fluent API.

```
// using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
// using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent;
// using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent.Models;

string policyName = "ListenAndSendPolicy";

// Define the claims
IList<AccessRights?> rights = new List<AccessRights?>();
rights.Add(AccessRights.Send);
rights.Add(AccessRights.Listen);

// Create the rule
SharedAccessAuthorizationRuleInner rule = await serviceBus.AuthorizationRules.Inner.CreateOrUpdateAuthorizationRuleAsync(
    serviceBus.ResourceGroupName,
    serviceBus.Name,
    policyName,
    rights);

// Get the policy
policy = await serviceBus.AuthorizationRules.GetByNameAsync(policyName);
```

This successfully created the policy

[image]